# FormatException: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character - Flutter Http Request

Tags: flutter, http, dart, get, flutter-channel

I make a http request in my flutter app with a simple url api:

```
Future<http.Response> getUsers() async {
  try {
    return await http
        .get('​https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10))
        .catchError((e) {
      print("=> catchError getUsers $e");
      return null;
    });
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    print("=> catch SocketException getUsers  $e");
    return null;
  } catch (e) {
    print("=> catch getUsers  $e");
    return null;
  }
}
```

And the error message is:

**err FormatException: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)
​https://reqres.in/api/users
^**

[image]

I have switched to different channels of the flutter version and I don't know the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
http.get(Uri.parse('​https://reqres.in/api/users'))
```